# How to check whether request is coming to my Server or not?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, port

I have one Software for port checking on remote server. we also use Telnet command for port checking for eg: for rdp port, we use C:> telnet 10.1.0.10 3389.

but the same thing i am doing from Software ( Total Network Monitoring software ). I am getting red sign, means through this software this port is unreachable.

So, i want to find out whether the request is going to my server on port 3389 or not.

**Can you suggest some tools or way, how can i track / monitor each and every request which is going to&from the server?**

Comment: so when you do the telnet x.x.x.x 3389 you are doing it on the server running  "Total Network Monitoring", correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Wireshark (Network Sniffer):
http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: or http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865